# Mapshaper running out of memory on R

Tags: r, memory, mapshaper

I'm using [rmapshaper](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmapshaper/index.html), the R wrapper of **MapShaper**, to simplify polygons without slivers and it works well on small shapefiles. However, when I run it on a larger one (~150M, ~5000 shapes), it runs out of memory. Here's a reproducible example:

```
# Load packages
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(knitr, readr, knitr, readr, plyr, dplyr, sp, rgdal,maptools, rgeos, rmapshaper)

# DOWNLOAD and UNZIP this file in the local folder.
# https://borders.ukdataservice.ac.uk/ukborders/easy_download/prebuilt/shape/infuse_ward_lyr_2011.zip

# read shapefile
uk_wards_2011 <- readOGR(dsn="infuse_ward_lyr_2011.shp")

# save attribute table
df = uk_wards_2011@data 
sdf = uk_wards_2011

# simplify without slivers
geom_simpl = rmapshaper::ms_simplify(sdf, keep = 0.01 ) # !!! This runs out of memory !!!
sdf_simpl = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame( geom_simpl, df )

summary(sdf_simpl)

# write to a geojson
writeOGR(obj = sdf_simpl, dsn = "simplified_shapes.geojson",layer='simple_shapes', driver="GeoJSON", overwrite_layer=T, delete_dsn=T)
```

This always generates this error:

```
#
# Fatal error in CALL_AND_RETRY_0
# Allocation failed - process out of memory
#
```

Any workaround? I tried with QGIS but it always generates slivers in the simplified polygons.

Comment: Just in case anyone thinks you can split the data into chunks, simplify each, and then merge - you can't because that doesn't guarantee the segments along the joins will match up without slivers.

Comment: In the end, it is a NodeJS memory limit that can be overcome by running the script directly, and not in R.